# Why does Conversion of DateTime to String with Formatting Option return an Integer?

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, type-conversion

My one line statement is trying to convert a date-time to a specified format as follows:

```
item.dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

However it is saying that it can't convert from integer to string (i.e. it is being cast as a string). Why is this returning a number when this variable in all other circumstances acts as a DateTime variable?

Further info:

- Item is a QueueItem from UiPath, it has two date values by the name of DueDate and DeferDate which are as follows
- The types for these, it states that it is of type `Date?`, which I believe refers to a type that is either a DateTime, or a null value.

How do I get around this so it doesn't strangely try to return an integer?

Comment: You are misunderstanding and/or misrepresenting something. There's nothing there that would generate that error message.  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  The code you posted is useless on its own regardless, because it's an expression that returns a value that you're not using.  Please provide all the relevant code and the full error information, including whether it's a compilation error or run-time exception.

Comment: Well, what is `item`? How is its `dateValue` property defined? Give some context.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. In hindsight the question was rushed and incomplete. Updated with hopefully sufficient information.